# Using Java, jsp and javascript

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp

I have a `.jsp` file like this:

```
List<MyClass> myClasses; // myObject

<script>
function f(v) {
 ...
 ...
 <p> <% myClasses(v).getString(); %> </p>
 ...
 ...
}
</script>
```

Inside the `javascript` function, i would like to use my Java object and the `v` parameter.

The error in using the variable as above is this:

```
v cannot be resolved to a variable
```

How can i do?

Thanks

Comment: JSP is at server. JS is at client.

Comment: Unfortunately, with this solution the error does not change

Comment: You could use AJAX to make a request to server. jQuery has easy API for that.

Comment: you cant use java objects inside the script ,,

Comment: then theres no need to have a seperate script tag for javascripts 
you will be able to do your transactions within the jsp tag sole purpose of javascript is changing the DOM you cant integrate it with java